# How to allow only three characters

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex check to fail if the string contains anything other than the letters L, M or R.

I have already tried whitelisting L, M and R and also blacklisting anything that isn't L, M or R, or so I thought. I probably failed at both.

```
if(Pattern.compile("^[LMR]$").matcher("MMMRMMMRMMLLMMK").matches()){
return false;
}
if(Pattern.compile("[^LMR]").matcher("MMMRMMMRMMLLMMK").matches()){
return false;
}
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^LMR]");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher("MMMRMMMRMMLLMMK");
if(pat.matches("[^LMR]", "MMMRMMMRMMLLMMK")){
return false;
}
```

Expected: String "MMMRMMMRMMLLMMK" fails.
Actual: I can put literally anything in that matcher and it will pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression might simply work:

```
^[LMR]*$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MZdIaP/1/)

#### [Ideone Java Demo](https://ideone.com/9R1Vdf)

#### Test

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

        final String regex = "^[LMR]*$";
        final String string = "MMMRMMMRMMLLMMK\n"
             + "MMMRMMMRMMLLMM\n"
             + "L\n"
             + "M\n"
             + "R\n";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/MZdIaP/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/MZdIaP/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Comment: The while loop proved unnecessary, however using the matcher.find() was the way to go in this case. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use `String#matches` here with the simple pattern `[LMR]*`:

```
String input = "MMMRMMMRMMLLMM";
if (input.matches("[LMR]*")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
else {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

Note that `String#match` by default assumes starting and ending anchors around the pattern, so we don't even need to provide `^` and `$`.